# interpolate Vim function arguments and shell commands

Tags: shell, vim

I've written a little .applescript file that can reload Safari.  I've tried to hook it's execution into vim's BufWritePost event, (so Safari auto-reloads on file save).

I've placed this in my .vimrc:

```
function! SaveAndReloadSafari(delay) 
   " THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
   !osascript ~/MySrc/applescript/reloadSafari.APPLESCRIPT a:delay
endfunction

if !exists("b:my_autocommands_loaded")
  let b:matts_autocommands_loaded = 1 

  au BufWritePost *.html,*\.css,*.js call SaveAndReloadSafari(0)
  au BufWritePost *.scss call SaveAndReloadSafari(2)
endif
```

As you can see, I want to add a 2 second delay after saving an .scss file (to allow my SCSS files to auto-compile to CSS)

I've confirmed that the only piece of the puzzle missing is my syntax for interpolating the a:delay with the shell command.  (Executing the command without a `delay` parameter works fine).

What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Would you mind to share your Apple Script? Sounds nice. ;)

Comment: Sorry :(  That was on my old work laptop --and I didn't back it up because I had stopped using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:exec`

```
exec '!osascript ~/MySrc/applescript/reloadSafari.APPLESCRIPT ' . a:delay
```